# How can I produce more than one result in sql ?

Tags: php, sql

The following is a query from which I have taken the result.But right now only one result is printing. I have more than one result in the database.. what should i do in order to print more than one result in header tag

```
<?php
    $sqlcategories = $ilance->db->query("SELECT q.title_spa FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "categories q LEFT 
                                        JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "profile_categories a ON (q.cid = a.cid)
                                        WHERE a.user_id = '" . $res_vendor['user_id'] . "'");
        if ($ilance->db->num_rows($sqlcategories) > 0)
        {
            while ($rows = $ilance->db->fetch_array($sqlcategories))
            {  
            $categories='<h3>'.$rows['title_spa'].'</h3>';
            }
         }
?>
```

Comment: `$categories.='<h3>'.$rows['title_spa'].'</h3>';`

Comment: I can't see where you printing that one line..

Comment: its a framework ilance hence, i haven't written that its in html page just calling there {category}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to change this line:

```
$categories = '<h3>'.$rows['title_spa'].'</h3>';
```

to for example:

```
$categories .= '<h3>'.$rows['title_spa'].'</h3>';
```

Comment: my doubt is should i use for loop ,or is it enough

Answer (score 0):

do like this... append string with .= operator

```
while ($rows = $ilance->db->fetch_array($sqlcategories))
{  
   $categories .='<h3>'.$rows['title_spa'].'</h3>';
}
echo $categories;
```

OR need to store in array then

```
while ($rows = $ilance->db->fetch_array($sqlcategories))
{  
   $categories[] ='<h3>'.$rows['title_spa'].'</h3>';
}
printr($categories);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before your query write:

```
$categories = "";
```

And then in `while` operator use concatenation (note the dot `.` before `=` operator)

```
$categories .= '<h3>'.$rows['title_spa'].'</h3>';
```

After that print `$categories` variable

```
echo $categories;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories='';
while ($rows = $ilance->db->fetch_array($sqlcategories))
{  
    $categories.='<h3>'.$rows['title_spa'].'</h3>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = '<h3>';    
while ($rows = $ilance->db->fetch_array($sqlcategories))
    {  
       $categories .= $rows['title_spa'];
    }
$categories .= '</h3>';
```